# Cloth simulation breaks mesh

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I wanted to simulate a cloth ribbon wrapped around a guitar. After baking a cloth simulation however, the ribbon breaks into individual pieces and I have no idea why. Can you help me?

[image: Broken down ribbon]

Ribbon was made by array and curve, simulation is using the "silk" preset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generated your ribbon, did you make sure that the Merge checkbox on the array modifier was checked?

If it isn't checked, none of the mesh segments will actually, joined. Checking it makes overlapping vertices in the array get merged and so the result will be a single connected mesh.

For more details see https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html

Comment: That's exactly it! Can't believe I forgot about it... Thank you.